# Complexity analysis of my Javascript code

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

Trying to get a grasp on Complexity Analysis and I have been reading this article: http://discrete.gr/complexity/ which is nicely written.

My complexity analysis of my Javascript snippet is: theta of n2 and also O(n2) after asymptotic behavior analysis.

My questions are:

1) **Is my algorithm O(n2)?, I have two for loops that grow with N, where n is the matrix**

2) **What about big O being worst-case scenario, so is my algorithm O(n3)?**

About my asymptotic behavior analysis: I think I have correctly "counted instructions" ignoring for loops with a condition based on a constant value and have rightly identified that as N grows large I have two for loops of concern and thus I came to the conclusion my alogrithm is theta of n2.

```js
function greatestAdjacent() {
    var height = 20;
    var width = 20;
    var consecutive = 4; //can only handle 20 % consecutive === 0;
    var grid = //grid[height][width]
        [[8, 02, 22, 97, 38, 15, 00, 40, 00, 75, 04, 05, 07, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8],
        [49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48, 04, 56, 62, 00],
        [81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30, 03, 49, 13, 36, 65],
        [52, 70, 95, 23, 04, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 01, 32, 56, 71, 37, 02, 36, 91],
        [22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40, 28, 66, 33, 13, 80],
        [24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 03, 45, 02, 44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84, 20, 35, 17, 12, 50],
        [32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70, 66, 18, 38, 64, 70],
        [67, 26, 20, 68, 02, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63, 8, 40, 91, 66, 49, 94, 21],
        [24, 55, 58, 05, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14, 88, 34, 89, 63, 72],
        [21, 36, 23, 9, 75, 00, 76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14, 00, 61, 33, 97, 34, 31, 33, 95],
        [78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94, 03, 80, 04, 62, 16, 14, 9, 53, 56, 92],
        [16, 39, 05, 42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24, 00, 17, 54, 24, 36, 29, 85, 57],
        [86, 56, 00, 48, 35, 71, 89, 07, 05, 44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21, 58, 51, 54, 17, 58],
        [19, 80, 81, 68, 05, 94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17, 77, 04, 89, 55, 40],
        [04, 52, 8, 83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 07, 97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26, 79, 33, 27, 98, 66],
        [88, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72, 03, 46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12, 32, 63, 93, 53, 69],
        [04, 42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18, 8, 46, 29, 32, 40, 62, 76, 36],
        [20, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59, 85, 74, 04, 36, 16],
        [20, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90, 01, 74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81, 16, 23, 57, 05, 54],
        [01, 70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52, 01, 89, 19, 67, 48]];

    var products = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i ++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            //can we check left
            if (j < width - consecutive) {
                var temp = 1;
                for (var k = 0; k < consecutive; k ++) {
                    temp *= parseInt(grid[i][j + k],10);
                }

                products.push(temp);
            }

            //can we check down
            if (i < height - consecutive) {
                var temp = 1;
                for (var k = 0; k < consecutive; k++) {
                    temp *= parseInt(grid[i + k][j], 10);
                }

                products.push(temp);
            }

            //can we check down right
            if (i < height - consecutive && j < width - consecutive) {
                var temp = 1;
                for (var k = 0; k < consecutive; k++) {
                    temp *= parseInt(grid[i + k][j + k], 10);
                }
                products.push(temp);
            }

            //can we check up right
            if (i > consecutive && j < width - consecutive) {
                var temp = 1;
                for (var k = 0; k < consecutive; k++) {
                    temp *= parseInt(grid[i - k][j + k], 10);
                }
                products.push(temp);
            }
        }
    }

    return Math.max.apply(Math, products);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

 $(function() {
   $('#h4Display').text(greatestAdjacent());
 });
</script>


<h4 id="h4Display"></h4>
```

Comment: you actually have 3 nested for loops

Comment: yes but the third loop does not grow directly with N, currently the third loop iterates only 4 times.

Comment: given `n = width * height` of your matrix, your algorithm scans each element once (in the first two nested loops); so up to here is O(n); but `consecutive` is a dimension of the problem too. if it is a constant (4), then still O(n), but if you want to see that as a variable, it would be O(cn) where c <= n

Comment: Wouldn't  I be able to Asymptotically remove c from O(cn) thus O(cn) is 0(n). Also wouldn't the algorithm be theta of n and O(n2) from a worst case analysis perspective?

Comment: "*the third loop does not grow directly with N*" What is `N`? That is, what is the input of your algorithm?

Comment: it depends; I didn't peek the details of your algorithm, so I cannot figure out `c` bounds, but if its possible that c == n (ignoring constants), then O(cn) -> O(n2).

Comment: You need to ask a specific question on this site that has a specific answer and make that be entirely what your question is abaout.  "Have a conversation about complexity analysis" is not an on-topic question for this site. This is a Q&A site which is different than a discussion site.